# How to make user automatically log in in Lubuntu 16.04?

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm

How do I make a user automatically log in in Lubuntu 16.04?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the answers for the linked question do not work with Lubuntu 16.04. This worked for me: http://www.neatlittleinsights.com/htdocs/lubuntu_16.04_autologin.html